# Prove $\det(kA)=k^n\det A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and $k$ be a scalar. Prove that $\det(kA)=k^n\det A$.

I really don't know where to start. Can someone give me a hint for this proof?

Comment: What definition of det are you using?

Comment: What row operations will get you from $A$ to $kA$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, let's recall what multiplication of a matrix by a scalar means:
When we multiply $\;kA$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $k$ a scalar, then 
every entry $a_{ij}$ of matrix $A$ is multiplied by $k$: i.e. $a_{ij}\mapsto ka_{ij}$ for each $a_{ij}$. That means for each row $i,\;0\leq i\leq n,\;$ we can factor out $k$.

Now...Recall the elementary row operations you've learned, and how each one of them affects the determinant of the matrix on which it is operating. Specifically, when any *one* row is multiplied by the scalar $k$, the determinant of $A$ becomes $\;k\det A$. So given that scalar multiplication of a square $n\times n$ matrix is equivalent to "row operating" on $n$ rows (by multiplying **each** row by the scalar $k$), we can conclude that $$\large\det (kA) = \underbrace{k\cdot k\cdot\cdots \cdot k}_{\large n \;\text{times}}\det A = k^n\det A$$

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are the column vectors of the matrix $A$, then we can think of $\det$ instead of a function that maps one matrix to the reals as a function that maps $n$ vectors to the reals. Indeed, this is the way we define $\det$, it is a multilinear function of $n$ vectors! Now, being multilinear means that for each $i$ with $1\leq i\leq n$ we have:

$$\det(v_1\dots,kv_i,\dots,v_n)=k\det(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_n)$$

$$\det(v_1,\dots,u+w,\dots,v_n)=\det(v_1,\dots,u,\dots,v_n)+\det(v_1,\dots,w,\dots,v_n)$$

We simply need to use the first property. If $A=\begin{pmatrix}v_1 & \cdots  & v_n\end{pmatrix}$ is your matrix, then by the usual definition of scalar multiplication for matrices we have $kA=\begin{pmatrix}kv_1 & \cdots & kv_n\end{pmatrix}$. In that case, we have that:

$$\det(kA)=\det(kv_1,\dots,kv_n)=k^n\det(v_1,\dots,v_n)=k^n\det(A)$$

Where $k^n$ appears because by multilinearity, for each index, one $k$ will be pulled out the $\det$. Pulling $n$ times the $k$ out, we get $k^n$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Determinant is a multi-linear function, it means that $\det(x_1,\ldots,kx_i + y_i,\ldots,x_n) = k \det(x_1,\ldots, x_n) + \det(x_1,\ldots, y_i, \ldots,x_n)$, in which the i-th component is the i-th row of the matrix. by using $y_i = 0$ your desired result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way of doing it:

If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of a matrix, then $\det(A)=\lambda_1\times\lambda_2\times\cdots\times\lambda_n$.

Let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ be its corresponding eigenvector. Now, $Ax=\lambda x$, then it is easy to see that $k\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $kA$ with the same eigenvector. Now, using the fact that each eigenvalue is being multiplied by $k$ and the determinant is product of eigenvalues, your proof follows.

I do wish to point out that the only reason I put this proof in is for fun. It is just another way of doing it. What you should be doing ideally is to work from the definition of a determinant taught to you.

Comment: Good intuition, bad proof. You need to argue that $k\lambda$ as an eigenvalue of $kA$ has the same algebraic multiplicity that $\lambda$ has as an eigenvalue of $A$; but this doesn't seem any easier than the original question.