# About a step in the proof about determinant of adjugate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was trying to understand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516127/the-determinant-of-adjugate-matrix/516177#516177) which is about $\det(\operatorname{adj}(A))$.

I came across a step: |A adj(A)|=|(|A|I)|. The next step was: |A||adj(A)|=|A|^n * I. I didn't get how |(|A|I)|= |A|^n * I.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Thank you. Would surely use the above information next time.

Comment: Are you trying to get that $A\cdot\operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)\cdot I$. (Which implies that $\det(A)\cdot\det(\operatorname{adj}(A))=\det(A)^n$.)

Comment: BTW does the steps you wrote there come from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/516177)?

Comment: Yes. Certainly. My query lies how we get det(A^_n)

Comment: Yes. The third step. I did follow that question

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your post correctly, you are asking about determinant of the matrix $|A|\cdot I$.

In general, if you multiply a row of matrix by a constant $c$, determinant is multiplied by the same constant.

Multiplying the whole matrix by a constant $c$ is the same as multiplying each row of this matrix by $c$. So for any constant $c$ and any $n\times n$ matrix $B$ you have
$$|cB|=c^n|B|.$$
See also here: [Prove $\det(kA)=k^n\det A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442240/prove-detka-kn-det-a)

This is just a special case where $B=I$ and $c=|A|$. So you get that
$$\det(|A|\cdot I)=|A|^n.$$

The answer you linked to writes this as $|A|^n\cdot|I|$, which is the same, since $|I|=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Got the flow. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.